# Typescript: how to capture keyboard events for a limited time

Tags: javascript, typescript, synchronization, typescript2.0

I'm coding some kind of video game where players take turns of N seconds, where in those N seconds they are able to enter keyboard inputs. Once the N seconds passed, the entered input would be returned (e.g. in an Array), processed and some actions will be performed.

The execution flow would be something similar to the following:

```
while (!gameOver) {
   // do some stuff like knowing who's player turn is it
   var enteredInput = captureKeyboardInputsFor(seconds);
   // process input & do actions
}
```

I do have the game logic well defined in mind, but I'm trying to figure out how can I do this with TypeScript, keeping my loop game synchronous (as the players play in turns), having the

`var enteredInput = captureKeyboardInputsFor(seconds);`

line waiting until the N seconds passed.

#### Edit:

Also, I was thinking about the possibility of having CPU Players. In that case there would be no need to wait or capture inputs:

```
while (!gameOver) {
   // do some stuff like knowing who's player turn is it

   var enteredInput;

   if (player.isHuman()) {
      enteredInput = captureKeyboardInputsFor(seconds);
   } else {
      enteredInput = calculateRandomCPUPlayerInput();
   }
   
   // process input & do actions
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can unbind the captureKeyboardInputs listener after N seconds have passed with the setTimeout function like shown below. Is this what you are looking for:

```
let fn = () => {
    // unbind capture keys event

    // process input & do actions
};

let a = setTimeout(this.fn, seconds * 1000);
```

if you need to modify this then you can do:

```
clearTimeout(a);
if (isProcessNow) {
    this.fn();
} else {
    a = setTimeout(this.fn, newSeconds * 1000);
}
```

Comment: I was also thinking about entering some kind of CPU Players, which in case it was their turn, there was no need to wait those `seconds`. I'll edit my post.

Comment: so setTimeout won't help you? I think that all you need is to stop reading keypress from the user after sometime, for that setTimeout will be suitable. Just to schedule the execution of a function that will stop the user keypressing events after some time.

Comment: I was through a bit of thinking... and definitely using timeout combined with some recursive executions will allow me to kind of handle the game loop synchronously!

Comment: Just another question in case you know: once I run a `setTimeout()`, is there a way to make it execute before the amount of milliseconds it was set to? For example: the first key input event triggers a second `setTimeout()` function for a time `T'`. If by the time this second timeout's callback is called the first timeout callback hasn't been executed yet: is there a way to make it to run before than expected? I hope I've explained myself correctly!

Comment: You can cancel a timeout like: var a = setTimeout(...);  .... clearTimeout(a); Then you can execute the function immediately or schedule another timeout.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It definitely helped me a lot to figure out kind of what I was looking for!! :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137699/discussion-between-charliebrownie-and-artemisian).